# Flutter: pub get failed (66)

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

When i try to implement scoped model, i get this error message:

[flutter_course] flutter packages get
Running "flutter packages get" in flutter_course...
Creation of temporary directory failed, path = 'C:\Program Files\flutter.pub-cache_temp\dir' (OS Error: Access is denied.
, errno = 5)

```
name: flutter_course
description: A new Flutter project.


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  scoped_model: ^1.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: `C:\Program Files\flutter.pub-cache_temp\dir` is a very weird directory for a temporary directory. Please check https://www.askvg.com/where-does-windows-store-temporary-files-and-how-to-change-temp-folder-location/ where temp points to on your system. What directory is Flutter installed on your system?

Comment: My flutter directory:   C:\Program Files\flutter

Comment: "do not install Flutter in a directory like C:\Program Files\ that requires elevated privileges)." https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install/windows#get-the-flutter-sdk

Comment: Can i delete previous temp location after changing it from "Environment Variables" ?

Comment: What value is there in "Environment Variables"? What folder do you mean with "previous temp folder location"?

Answer (score 15):

What worked for me is: `flutter pub cache repair`

[reference](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16100#issuecomment-403934886)

Comment: pub is repeated twice.

Answer (score 9):

**I FINALLY GOT THE SOLUTION**

Hello guys I finally found a solution to this error.

So the problem is first caused because temporary files could not be created in the /bin or .pub-Cache

To fix this go to their respective folders which are in the flutter folder and the first start with the bin folder and change its security options to allow for **ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES** and then the .pub-Cache the same .

Run flutter doctor and if you get a license error just follow the steps given by flutter doctor and you are good to go.

Comment: this not in the windows specific flutter docs or in the suggestions from the dart and flutter dsk teams..everyone on ms windows should bookmark this!

Comment: This solution worked like a charm. It should be granted as an official troubleshooting solution for this issue. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: How i make this on Mac?

Answer (score 8):

Enable in your windows settings the Developer Mode.
[image: Enable Developer Mode in Windows]

Answer (score 7):

Try to clean Flutter: `flutter clean` and then update pub with: `flutter packages upgrade` or update Flutter with: `flutter upgrade`.

Answer (score 7):

This happens to be an active [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1798) and the flutter team is currently working on it. The problem is specific to the Windows operating system. You can try the following workarounds for now:

1) Make sure your installation does not reside in any directory which requires special privileges like `Program Files`. If that's the case, you can try running it as admin for now but you should change your installation directory to a user's data directory as soon as possible (@Günter Zöchbauer has already pointed this out in the comments).

2) Try restarting your machine.

3) Try deleting the `.dart_tools` folder and also try clearing the cache in `flutter/bin/cache`

4) Try disabling your antivirus and/or windows defender temporarily (although it's not really possible for people working on corporate machines). This issue could have been caused by an active antivirus locking your files temporarily.

Comment: I've no idea why Avast kept prompting when I ran `flutter pub get`, until I ran into this issue... found this answer a bit too late, but great one 

Answer (score 4):

If you have tried all answers here.

You should try this, it worked for me.

1. (in android studio) Delete the pubspec.lock file in your project.
2. (in android studio) Execute this-- Tools > Flutter > Flutter clean
3. Go to flutter sdk folder where you have downloaded it. In my case C:\src\flutter\
4. Run this below command.

   C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin>**flutter pub cache repair**

After completion run pub get again in your android studio. It should work.

Answer (score 4):

Turning on developer mode solved my issue on Windows 10.

1. Delete temp folder in pub cache.
2. Do pub repair `flutter pub cache repair`.
3. Turn on developer mode in windows settings.
4. Flutter clean and delete pub.lock if exist.
5. Try `flutter pub get`.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

An easy solution that worked for me on Windows was to run Android Studio as administrator.

After that, the error no longer appeared.

Comment: Please don't run Android Studio as administrator, it would make it easier for a bad plugin or something to modify your computer

Comment: I agree with @activout.se's comment, instead adjust permission for that project's root folder and its all childs

Answer (score 3):

Because I switched the Flutter version, the following operation worked for me

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the Flutter sdk using : flutter upgrade.

And also scoped_model in this link [scoped model](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scoped_model/versions/0.2.0#-versions-tab-) is showing dart 2 incompatible

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because "packages get" command attemp to delete file in ...flutter.pub-cache_temp. Delete files manually in this loction, this is may not perfect solutions but it's works.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes newly installed packages could cause this. Uninstall and install package again

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded flutter sdk and extracted file in C:\FlutterDev\ and then start android studio
remember to provide flutter sdk path if you changed

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation when I upgraded the flutter version to the new 2.2.
As a solution, I ran the command line as administrator (or terminal for linux users) in the Project folder and run the following commands:

1. `flutter pub cache repair`
   2.`flutter pub get`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the solutions mentioned above none worked for me.

Then I went to file(any .dart) which has dependency error then click on get dependency. it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried
Flutter clean X
Flutter pub cache repair X
Add Security X
Delete Temp X

last ....
I just open the windows setting  **developer mode** O
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to run

```
flutter pub get
```

it in an external terminal not from android studio

Also I set windows as developer, I ran in terminal and turned developer mode on

```
start ms-settings:developers
```

not sure which one helped.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it solved my error,

terminal->`flutter clean`, then `flutter pub get` after this, you will get the reason for the error, in my case I was using the latest version of path dependencies(`path ^1.8.3`), but SDK depended on the path ^1.8.2,
so I changed path dependency from path `^1.8.3` to path `^1.8.2`, in `pubspec.yaml`, and the error was solved...

Answer (score 0):

All the above solutions didn't work for me
So I tried this

I removed pubspec.lock file and run `flutter pug get`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when I tried to run the official sample code for flutter web "Gallery".

My solution was to upgrade to master. Run "flutter channel master".
But take care, since after running this, you will switch to the master channel. I recommend to switch back to the stable channel, as soon as possible again. Because the master channel could have some hard bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I delete pubspec.lock  file , then

> flutter pub get

Answer (score 0):

##### Fixed

Doing an upgrade to flutter fix this:

```bash
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a permission problem that error code so I just run chmod command for that particular project's folder and the problem gone. Change permission code as your requirements, in my case it wasn't an important project.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 .
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're on windows first run cmd as administor
then run `flutter pub cache clean` then run `flutter run -d <your-device>` it should work
if your'e on mac or linux do the run part using `sudo`