# Flutter : no files in .dart_tool directory

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I have downloaded a source code from internet just to learn flutter, it's backend is on php and working fine but when i run

> flutter pug get

I am getting error of

```
    Cannot open file, path ='.\.dart_tool\package_config.json' (OS Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
        , errno = 3).
pub get failed (66; , errno = 3))
Process finished with exit code 66
```

i am posting this question here because i have searched already in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)

but i didn't get any useful answers.

here is result of

> flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1110], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio
[√] VS Code (version 1.59.0)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

your help would be appericiated. thank you.

Comment: take a look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233412/flutter-pub-get-failed-66

Comment: @Benyamin thanks for your comment. i read the Answer no 2 . can you help  me a little bit about this answer?

Comment: @Benyamin i tried steps as answered there but still same error.

Comment: try all of the answers to see if either of them works

Comment: @Benyamin thanks for your time again, i tried everything. now i got that there is no file in .dart_tool folder, i manually deleted it and it's generating by flutter self during build proccess.