# flutter：get error when I pull flutter dependencies

Tags: flutter

When I use the command `flutter pub get` I get an error,

> 'pub get failed (66; Creation failed, path =
> '/Users/developer/xxxxxxxx' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno =
> 13))'

Comment: can you try invalide caches and restart from android studio tab?

Comment: From which path are you running the command? It's the root path of the project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: pub get failed (66)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233412/flutter-pub-get-failed-66)